# python pandas groupby detail and sum

Tags: python, pandas

here is my target output,
I want to show groupby sum() by pandas

But I can only print sum() or detail

How can I combine this two output

pic 1 is my code , pic 2 is what I expect.

Thanks everyone.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7SCx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odIRv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do group by on 'area' and then do sum() on that group using function

```
def get_total(x):
    x.loc['total'] = ['','',x['amount'].sum()]
    return x
   
df.groupby(['area']).apply(get_total)
```

Comment: There are no anonymous functions being used here.

Comment: Thank u!!!! it works!!!